# Calling a block from the view inside a helper using `link_to`

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, haml, actionviewhelper

In this fictive but representative example, we want to create a Rails 7.0 view helper that takes a block, feeds the block a magic word, takes the block's output and produces a link pointing to some path, displaying the block's output as the label.

Here's our non-working approach in the view helper:

```rb
def magic_link(&block)
  helpers.link_to('#somepath') do
    block.call('ABRACADABRA')
  end
end
```

And in the HAML view, we use it as follows:

```
= magic_link do |magic_word|
  %h1
    The magic word is:
    = magic_word
```

```html
<a href="#somepath">
<h1>
The magic word is:
ABRACADABRA
</h1>
</a>
```

However, the actual result is:

```html
<h1>
The magic word is:
ABRACADABRA
</h1>

<a href="#somepath">
<h1>
The magic word is:
ABRACADABRA
</h1>
</a>
```

As can be seen, the block is rendered twice, likely for the same reason as described in [Why is a block from a view rendered twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27746311/why-is-a-block-from-a-view-rendered-twice)

However, due to the need of the link around the text, the solutions described in the stackoverflow question linked above will not work. Returning `nil` at the end of the block renders only the first occurrence, i.e. the block's result without the link.

A working but undesired solution would be to change the HAML to:

```
= magic_link do |magic_word|
  - capture do
    %h1
      The magic word is:
      = magic_word
```

This works because the `-` tells HAML to discard the result of the capture block, removing the unwanted duplicate. However, this is undesired because we want to keep the helper's interface clean; needing to call `capture` inside the view in order to use a helper properly is not an option.

How can the helper be rewritten to make the original HAML (without `capture`) work without producing the unwanted duplicate?